# Showing both sides of street from roads layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am trying to show parking occupancy during peak hours and I need to offset a roads layer to show on both sides of the street.

How to get the lines to offset?

I am trying to make a map like the one shown below

[image]

Comment: Buffer then convert buffers to lines

Comment: Check out ArcMap's Cartographic Representations, they allow you to apply rules to symbology like offsetting lines... http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/what-are-representations-.htm

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using ArcMap, you will use your roads polyline layer as input for a Buffer (Analysis) process, out of the Geoprocessing Toolbox.  Set the width to buffer as half the distance you want the sides of the street to be apart - so for example, if you want 100 feet between the edge lines, you will enter the buffer as 50 feet, as shown here:
[image]

After that is complete, you will have a polygon layer representing your roads - convert this back to polylines with the Feature to Line tool.  Make sure that "Preserve Attribtues" box is checked, as this will allow you to symbolize the edges of the roads differently based on their names, or any other distinct feature:

[image]

If you are using QGIS or another program, you will follow the same steps and tools, but they will have slightly different names.